# JSON to XML in Scala and dealing with Option() result

Tags: scala, scala-option

Consider the following from the Scala interpreter:

```
scala> JSON.parseFull("""{"name":"jack","greeting":"hello world"}""")
res6: Option[Any] = Some(Map(name -> jack, greeting -> hello world))
```

Why is the Map returned in Some() thing? And how do I work with it?

I want to put the values in an xml template:

```
<test>
  <name>name goes here</name>
  <greeting>greeting goes here</greeting>
</test>
```

What is the Scala way of getting my map out of Some(thing) and getting those values in the xml?

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers. There seems to be differing opinions on using pattern matching or not. Don't know if this is 'n purest war or not, but I will also investigate them with my faithful "Programming in Scala book" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two separate problems.

1. It's typed as `Any`.
2. Your data is inside an `Option` and a `Map`.

Let's suppose we have the data:

```
val x: Option[Any] = Some(Map("name" -> "jack", "greeting" -> "hi"))
```

and suppose that we want to return the appropriate XML if there is something to return, but not otherwise.  Then we can use `collect` to gather those parts that we know how to deal with:

```
val y = x collect {
  case m: Map[_,_] => m collect {
    case (key: String, value: String) => key -> value
  }
}
```

(note how we've taken each entry in the map apart to make sure it maps a string to a string--we wouldn't know how to proceed otherwise.  We get:

```
y: Option[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] =
  Some(Map(name -> jack, greeting -> hi))
```

Okay, that's better!  Now if you *know* which fields you want in your XML, you can ask for them:

```
val z = for (m <- y; name <- m.get("name"); greet <- m.get("greeting")) yield {
  <test><name>{name}</name><greeting>{greet}</greeting></test>
}
```

which in this (successful) case produces

```
z: Option[scala.xml.Elem] =
  Some(<test><name>jack</name><greeting>hi</greeting></test>)
```

and in an unsuccessful case would produce `None`.

If you instead want to wrap whatever you happen to find in your map in the form `<key>value</key>`, it's a bit more work because Scala doesn't have a good abstraction for tags:

```
val z = for (m <- y) yield <test>{ m.map { case (tag, text) => xml.Elem(null, tag, xml.Null, xml.TopScope, xml.Text(text)) }}</test>
```

which again produces

```
z: Option[scala.xml.Elem] =
  Some(<test><name>jack</name><greeting>hi</greeting></test>)
```

(You can use `get` to get the contents of an `Option`, but it will throw an exception if the `Option` is empty (i.e. `None`).)

Answer (score 6):

You should probably use something like this:

```
res6 collect { case x: Map[String, String] => renderXml(x) }
```

Where:

```
def renderXml(m: Map[String, String]) = 
  <test><name>{m.get("name") getOrElse ""}</name></test>
```

The [`collect`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) method on `Option[A]` takes a `PartialFunction[A, B]` and is a combination of `filter` (by a predicate) and `map` (by a function). That is:

```
opt collect pf
opt filter (a => pf isDefinedAt a) map (a => pf(a))
```

Are both equivalent. When you have an *optional* value, you should use `map`, `flatMap`, `filter`, `collect` etc to transform the option in your program, avoiding *extracting* the option's contents either via a pattern-match or via the `get` method. You should *never*, **ever** use `Option.get` - it is the canonical sign that *you are doing it wrong*. Pattern-matching should be avoided because it represents a fork in your program and hence adds to cyclomatic complexity - the only time you might wish to do this might be for performance

---

Actually you have the issue that the result of the `parseJSON` method is an `Option[Any]` (the reason is that it is an `Option`, presumably, is that the parsing may not succeed and `Option` is a more graceful way of handling `null` than, well, `null`).

But the issue with my code above is that the `case x: Map[String, String]` cannot be checked at runtime due to type erasure (i.e. scala can check that the option contains a `Map` but not that the `Map`'s type parameters are both `String`. The code will get you an *unchecked* warning.

Answer (score 6):

An `Option` is returned because `parseFull` has different possible return values depending on the input, or it may fail to parse the input at all (giving `None`). So, aside from an optional `Map` which associates keys with values, an optional `List` can be returned as well if the JSON string denoted an array.

Example:

```
scala> import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON._
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON._

scala> parseFull("""{"name":"jack"}""")
res4: Option[Any] = Some(Map(name -> jack))

scala> parseFull("""[ 100, 200, 300 ]""")
res6: Option[Any] = Some(List(100.0, 200.0, 300.0))
```

You might need *pattern matching* in order to achieve what you want, like so:

```
scala> parseFull("""{"name":"jack","greeting":"hello world"}""") match {
     |   case Some(m) => Console println ("Got a map: " + m)
     |   case _ =>
     | }
Got a map: Map(name -> jack, greeting -> hello world)
```

Now, if you want to generate XML output, you can use the above to iterate over the key/value pairs:

```
import scala.xml.XML

parseFull("""{"name":"jack","greeting":"hello world"}""") match {
  case Some(m: Map[_,_]) =>
    <test>
      {
        m map { case (k,v) =>
          XML.loadString("<%s>%s</%s>".format(k,v,k))
        }
      }
    </test>

  case _ =>
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`parseFull` returns an `Option` because the string may not be valid JSON (in which case it will return `None` instead of `Some`).

The usual way to get the value out of a `Some` is to pattern match against it like this:

```
result match {
    case Some(map) =>
        doSomethingWith(map)
    case None =>
        handleTheError()
}
```

If you're certain the input will always be valid and so you don't need to handle the case of invalid input, you can use the `get` method on the `Option`, which will throw an exception when called on `None`.

Comment: Pattern matching on `Option` should be avoided

Comment: @oxbow_lakes - Pattern matching on `Option` is usually clunky _unless_ you want to match on the contents as well.

Comment: +1 I endorse this answer, and heartily disagree with the "should be avoided" and "clunky" statements. Pattern matching is the simplest and clearest way to solve this problem.