# Working with Some() and Option() in Scala

Tags: scala

I've been fighting with the concept of the functional way of parsing a JSON string in Scala and ran flat into the wall with Option(something) being returned. I [popped the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289647/avoiding-some-headache)and the helpful answers came streaming in.

The problem is, as someone being pretty new to Scala, what is the correct way?

Currently I'm doing this:

```
import util.parsing.json.JSON._

object JsonSoap {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = parseFull("""{"name":"Joe","surname":"SOAP"}""")

    val y = x collect {
      case m: Map[_, _] => m collect {
        case (key: String, value: String) => key -> value
      }
    }

    val z = for (m <- y; name <- m.get("name"); surname <- m.get("surname"))
    yield {
      <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soap:Body>
          <Person>
            <Name>{name}</Name>
            <Surname>{surname}</Surname>
          </Person>
        </soap:Body>
      </soap:Envelope>
    }

    println(z)
  }
}
```

I'm still stuck with Some()

Is there a nice pattern to solving my problem? Surely this has to be well explored territory. How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are not "stuck" with `Some` - you have the **advantage** that you have a `Some`! In Java, you would be stuck with a value whose type did not express the fact that it might not actually exist!

```
MyThing recklessly = apiCall.getMeAThing();
recklessly.iSureHopeImNotNull();  //OH NOES!
```

Compare that to this

```
apiCall.getMeAThing foreach (_.cannotPossiblyBeNull)
```

The `Option` datatype means that the "might not exist" bit of your query is actually baked into the return type of the query. Please stick with `Option` - in a few weeks you will be pulling out your hair when you go to write Java code and it's not there!

#### Shooting down your objections

*You might say*:

> Aw, but I need to take the value I have and add 1 to it

I say:

```
apiCall.getMeAThing map (_ + 1)
```

*You might say*

> Aw, but I need to pass it to a method, defaulting to the empty String if I have null

I say:

```
foo( apiCall.getMeAThing getOrElse "" )
```

*You might say*

> Aw, but I use that value to call another API method and get something else

I say:

```
apiCall.getMeAThing flatMap apiCall.getMeAnotherThing
```

*You'll definitely say*

> Aw but that's awfully inefficient with all those object creations

I say: "try it, it will be just fine"

Comment: Thanks Oxbow. Point taken ;-)

Comment: ad of the Option class :) probably it makes sense to make such (or even video!!!) ads for another scala classes that force functional style :))))))))

Answer (score 10):

Usually when you have a result wrapped in an Option, you want to use either `match` or one of the monadic methods `map`, `flatMap`, or `foreach`.  For example, in your case we could do any of these

```
val output = z match {
  case Some(xml) => xml
  case None => "Invalid JSON"
}
println(output)

//or
z.foreach{println} //won't print anything if z is None

//or
println(z.getOrElse("Invalid JSON"))
```

In most cases you should avoid something like:

```
if (z == None) {
  println("Invalid")
} else {
  println(Z.get)
}
```

Comment: This is poor advice; you should prefer `getOrElse`, `map`, `flatMap` etc to `match`

Comment: I think it should be self-evident here compared to the other examples  I included that pattern matching on an Option is overly verbose, but the asker seems unaware of the ways to use it so I am merely giving an overview of the various methods.

Comment: Well, I don't seem to be able to remove my downvote, even though the post has been edited

Answer (score 4):

Here's the thing: you may not have gotten the data you expect, in which case it is not possible to compute `z`. So the answer to your question really depends on *your* answer to one question: what will you do when you cannot compute `z`?

Suppose, for instance, that you just don't want to print anything if `z` cannot be computed (ie, it is `None`). In this case, you do this:

```
z foreach println
```