# Scala Map#get and the return of Some()

Tags: scala, dictionary

Im using scala `Map#get` function, and for every accurate query it returns as `Some[String]`

IS there an easy way to remove the `Some`?

Example:

```
def searchDefs{
    print("What Word would you like defined? ")
    val selection = readLine
    println(selection + ":\n\t" + definitionMap.get(selection))
  }
```

When I use this method and use the following Input:

```
What Word would you like defined? Ontology
```

The returned Value is:

```
Ontology:
    Some(A set of representational primitives with which to model a domain of knowledge or discourse.)
```

I would like to remove the Some() around that.

Any tips?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9364250/working-with-some-and-option-in-scala

Comment: The wonderful thing about `Option` is that it forces you to handle the `None` case.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to deal with the `Option` type. First of all, however, do realize how much better it is to have this instead of a potential `null` reference! Don't try to get rid of it simply because you are used to how Java works.

As someone else recently stated: stick with it for a few weeks and you will moan each time you have to get back to a language which doesn't offer `Option` types.

Now as for your question, the simplest and riskiest way is this:

```
mymap.get(something).get
```

Calling `.get` on a `Some` object retrieves the object inside. It does, however, give you a runtime exception if you had a `None` instead (for example, if the key was not in your map).

A much cleaner way is to use `Option.foreach` or `Option.map` like this:

```
scala> val map = Map(1 -> 2)
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2)

scala> map.get(1).foreach( i => println("Got: " + i))
Got: 2

scala> map.get(2).foreach( i => println("Got: " + i))

scala>
```

As you can see, this allows you to execute a statement if and only if you have an actual value. If the `Option` is `None` instead, nothing will happen.

Finally, it is also popular to use pattern matching on `Option` types like this:

```
scala> map.get(1) match {
     |  case Some(i) => println("Got something")
     |  case None => println("Got nothing")
     | }
Got something
```

Comment: `mymap(something)` looks prettier.

Comment: @elbowich: Yes, `mymap(something)` seems to be a good alternative when you know that `something` is certainly contained in the map.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like using `.getOrElse(String)` and use something like "None" as a default i.e. `.getOrElse("None")`.

Answer (score 2):

In modern scala you can just `map(key)`

Answer (score 2):

The [`apply`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#apply(key:K):V) method on the `Map` can be used to retrieve the value without the `Option` wrapper, throwing an exception if the key does not exist.

```
val map = Map(1 -> 2)
map(1) // 2
map(2) // NoSuchElementException
```

> `def apply(key: K): V` 
>  Retrieves the value which is associated with the given key. This method invokes the default method of the map if there is no mapping from the given key to a value. Unless overridden, the default method throws a NoSuchElementException.

Use [`getOrElse`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#getOrElse%5BV1%3E:V%5D(key:K,default:=%3EV1):V1) to return a default value when the key is not found (instead of throwing an exception).

```
val map = Map(1 -> 2)
map.getOrElse(1, -1) // 2
map.getOrElse(2, -1) // -1
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, replaced with .Key() to resolve.
Solution:
definitionMap(selection)