# Trouble implementing Perceptron in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala, perceptron

I'm taking the **CalTech online course** Learning From Data, and I'm stumped with creating a `Perceptron` in Scala. I chose Scala because I'm learning it and wanted to challenge myself. I understand the theory, and I also understand others' solutions in Python and Ruby. But I can't figure out why my own Scala code doesn't work.

For a background in the `Perceptron` code: [Learning_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Learning_algorithm)

I'm running Scala 2.11 on OSX 10.10.

Per the algorithm, I start off with weights (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), where weight[2] is a learned bias component. I've already generated a test set in the space [-1, 1],[-1,1] on the X-Y plane. I do this by a) picking two random points and drawing a line through them, then b) generating some other random points and calculating if they are on one side of the line or the other. As far as I can tell by plotting it in Python, this generates linearly separable data.

My next step is to take my initialized weights and check against every point to find miss-classified points, i.e. points that don't generate the right +1 or -1 result. Here is the code that simply calculates dot-product of the weight and the vector x:

```
def h(weight:List[Double], p:Point ): Double = if ( (weight(0)*p.x + weight(1)*p.y + weight(2)) > 0) 1 else -1
```

It's the initial weights, so they are all miss-classified. I then update the weights, like so:

```
def newH(weight:List[Double], p:Point, y:Double): List[Double] = {
val newWt = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Double](0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
newWt(0) = weight(0) + p.x*y
newWt(1) = weight(1) + p.y*y
newWt(2) = weight(2) + 1*y    
return newWt.toList
}
```

Then I identify miss-classified points again by checking the test set against the value output by h() above, and continue iterating.

This follows the algorithm (or is supposed to, at least) that Prof Yaser shows here: [Library](http://work.caltech.edu/library/013.html)

The problem is that the algorithm never converges. My weights -- the third component of which is the bias -- keep getting more negative or more positive. My weight vector after every adjustment resembles this:

```
Weights: List(16.43341624736786, 11627.122008800507, -34130.0)
Weights: List(15.533397436141968, 11626.464265227318, -34131.0)
Weights: List(14.726969361305237, 11626.837346673012, -34132.0)
Weights: List(14.224745154380798, 11627.646470665932, -34133.0)
Weights: List(14.075232982635498, 11628.026384592056, -34134.0)
```

I'm a Scala newbie so my code is probably atrocious. But am I missing something in Scala, e.g. reassignment, that could be causing my weight to be messed up? Or have I completely misunderstood how the `Perceptron` even operates? Is my weight update just wrong?

Thanks for any help you can give me on this!

Comment: Judging based on Wikipedia, I think your update formula is wrong. I think it should be something like `newWt(0) = weight(0) + alpha * (y - h(weight, p)) * p.x` where `0 < alpha <= 1` is the learning rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Till. I've discovered the two problems with my code and I'll share them, but to address your point: Someone else asked about this on the class's forum and it looks like what the Wiki formula does is simply to change the learning rate. Alpha can be picked randomly, and y-h(weight, p) would give you weights like

```
-1-1 = 2
```

In the case that y=-1 and h()=1, or

```
1-(-1) = 2
```

In the case that y=1 and h()=-1

My/the class formula takes `1*p.x` instead of `alpha*2`, which seems to be a matter of different learning rates. Hope that makes sense.

My two problems were as follows:

1. The `y` value passed into the recalculation formula `newH` needs to be the *target value of y*, that is, the "correct y" that was discovered while generating the test points. I was passing in the y that was generated through h(), which is the guessed-at function. This makes sense obviously since we are looking to correc the weight by using the target y, not the incorrect y.
2. I was doing a comparison of target `y` and `h()=y`in Scala, but was comparison an element obtained from a map through `.get()`. My Scala map looks like `Map[Point,Double]` where the `Double` value refers to the `y` value generated during the test set creation. But doing a `.get()` gives you `Option[Double]` and not a `Double` value at all. This is explained in [Scala Map#get and the return of Some()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389902/scala-mapget-and-the-return-of-some) and makes a lot of sense now. I did `map.get(<some Point>).get()` for now, since I was focusing on debugging and not code perfection, and then I was accurately able to compare two `Double` values.